# Tor crashes on startup-I don't think it's my antivirus (WINDOWS 11)

Tags: error

Tor crashes on start-up every time. I have tried reinstalling from scratch. I have tried disabling my firewall and made sure Tor is allowed through the firewall. I have no anti-virus open and disabled the Windows one. I didn't see anything in Event Viewer but I might not have been using it right, idk. Sometimes (but not always) a popup comes up before it crashes again which says Tor exited during startup. I have tried restarting my PC of course. Can't see any logs.

Please note I am very stupid and tech illiterate so I might need to be walked through any solutions

Answer (score 0):

It can be Microsoft's *feature* to bind system networking services on port 9050 - happens since Windows 7 SP1. To fix it just select a different port for your proxy - like 19050 - and it will be just fine

Comment: How do I do this sorry? I don't really understand.

Comment: use your own torrc file - supply it in a command line for your tor.exe - and in this file change all the things you need including the custom port number. Like that: "C:\tor\Tor\tor.exe -f c:\tor\torrc.txt"